# Merge multiple rows for each ID so that the most information is collected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have multiple rows for each ID, I don't want the most recent, I would like to merge these into the most complete entry for each ID. Each ID may have a different number of associated rows.
I'd like to do this in either Alteryx or SQL but not sure at all where to begin.

for example:

```
row    ID                 ColA         ColB        ColC
 1    1234                             red         
 2    1234               purple        red        
 3    1234                                          blue
```

Desired result:

```
row    ID            ColA      ColB      ColC
1      1234        Purple      red       blue
```

Comment: Are the empty columns null values or empty strings?

Comment: Stu, they are empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a simple aggregation should do the trick.

**For Example**

```
Select row = min(row)
      ,ID
      ,ColA = max(ColA)
      ,ColB = max(ColB) 
      ,ColC = max(ColC)
 From  YourTable
 Group By ID
```

Comment: Thanks John, I could have guessed that it was something so easy I missed it. I appreciate the quick answer!